# SD card will not mount and dissapears when trying to do anything in gparted

Tags: fedora, sd-card

I am using Fedora 35 and am just trying to mount an SD card but it's not working. Using `lsblk` I can see the device, but when I try to do anything like `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0 /mnt`, I get the error `mount: /mnt: /dev/mmcblk0 is not a valid block device.` and it disappears when from lsblk for a few seconds. If I try to use gparted, the same thing happens.

If I look at `journalctl -f`, I see the following:
[image]

I dual boot windows on the same laptop, and the SD card works fine with it. I have reinstalled udisk2 but that didn't help. Any ideas on things to try here?

Comment: Can you mount other SD cards? ... or just not this specific one?

Comment: That's the next thing I was planning on testing. Unfortunately I don't have another SD card to test now. Will be getting another one in a few days.

Comment: Does that device show up in `fwupdmgr get-devices`?